# How to fast rewrite PhantomJS scripts for Headless Chrome?

Tags: phantomjs, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless, code-migration

Is there a simple/fast solution to rewrite PhantomJS scripts for Headless Chrome? Share a lifehack please.

Answer (score 0):

[puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) is the closest to the original Phantomjs in terms of terminology and syntax.